# OPENCV LNK 2001 Error: "unresolved external symbol" while adding to/modifying OPENCV source files

Tags: c++, opencv, linker-errors, lnk2001

I need  to modfiy some OPENCV  source files (VS 2019, C++) but get this error.
I have  OpenCV version 4.6. which is  installed with CMAKE and it  works  well untill I try  to add a  new function in source files.
More precilsely,  I have  performed the  following

1. I have  modified source feature2d.cpp  by adding the following test function

```
void mynewtest()
{
    std::cout<<" this is  opencv";
}
```

2. Added  in source features2d.hpp  the following

```
void  mynewtest();
```

3. Then I build ALL_BUILD  and build INSTALL using OpenCV.sln in build folder
4. Next, I have tried to run the following standard code, which gives LNK 2001 Error

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>
#include <iostream>


using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    mynewtest(); //--- ADDED FUNCTION

    //-----------------------------------------------------------;
    std::string image_path = samples::findFile("starry_night.jpg");
    Mat img = imread(image_path, IMREAD_COLOR);
    if (img.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "Could not read the image: " << image_path << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    imshow("Display window", img);
    int k = waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    if (k == 's')
    {
        imwrite("starry_night.png", img);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I comment  mynewtest(); then  the code starts normally.
As I  understand  smth  is with  linking lib libriries but  all the libs are linked well

have tried to re-build opencv using cmake

Comment: Maybe you did not export  mynewtest() from the opencv dlls. If you don't export a function in mscv its hidden from the linker.

Comment: In the header file, your function needs to be declared as `CV_EXPORTS void mynewtest();`.

Comment: Thanks !   macro CV_EXPORTS    solves the problem